# Sys is undefined - ajax issue in IE 7 only

Tags: asp.net, ajax, internet-explorer-7, iis-6, windows-server-2003

I have a weird issue that only seems to be affecting IE 7. The web site is a 3.5 c# asp.net website that utilizes ajax and the ajax control toolkit deployed to a win 2003 server. Everything appears to be correct in the web.config. In fact, everything works perfectly in IE6 and Firefox 3. It is only in IE7 that I get the dreaded sys is undefined error.

Also, the site appears to be working fine for IE7 on a different installation of the same code. That server is running win 2003 with very similar setups.

Since this appears to be a server issue, are there any kind of settings that would prevent ajax-enabled sites from displaying properly in IE7?

Comment: do you have a code sample, or can you clarify where exactly you are getting the exception? e.g. can you send, do you receive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Believe it or not, but emptying the temporary internet files solved the problem. I hate things like this!

Answer (score 1):

I know you said that everything appears to be correct in web.config, but still check it again on that server for this:

```
<add verb="GET,HEAD"
   path="ScriptResource.axd"
   type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
   validate="false"/>
```

in the `<httpHandlers>` element.

If it is there, then in IE7 do View Source, and grab one of the ScriptResource.axd script reference URLs and just paste it into the browser and see what it comes back with.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error when we moved to a new version of the AJAX Control Toolkit, and the new dll for that library didn't propagate out correctly when I rebuilt. So clearing the temp inet files is what I had to do also.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the "Combine Scripts" functionality of the AJAX Toolkit Script Manager? It's known to cause problems with some browsers/proxies, leading to the very error you're describing. I think it's enabled by default in 3.5, so you might want to look at shutting it off and seeing if your problems persist.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that it is only IE7?  Maybe other browsers are supressing the error.  Firebug on Firefox might bring this to the surface.

The two times I have seen something like this were
a)  using jQuery in the same project as ASP.NET Ajax, here jQuery's noConflict method helped out

b)  Check the position of the ScriptManager on your page, make sure that it isn't being included in a Content Page but referenced above in a Master Page or something like that

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

None of the suggestion worked for me, but when added the following under `<system.web>`, it worked!

```
<httpHandlers>
   <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
   <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
   <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
   <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false"/>
  </httpHandlers>

  <httpModules>
   <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
  </httpModules>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try placing your javascript code below `<asp:ToolkitScriptManager>`